# Canvas: Two balls having the same color

Tags: javascript, oop, web-applications, html5-canvas, game-development

I'm trying to learn canvas and I'm at a point that I want to spawn balls of different colors.

The problem is when I instantiate a new object called `ball2` it seems that `ball` doesn't retain its original color when it was instat.

How do I keep the first ball have its original color?

To recreate the issue:

- Have [live server](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server-plus-plus) installed in VScode
- Copy paste the code below in the same directory
- Start a live server with `index.html`

## This is the main entry of the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Draw a circle</title>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import World from './World.js'

function createHiPPICanvas(width, height) {
  const ratio = window.devicePixelRatio
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')

  canvas.width = width * ratio
  canvas.height = height * ratio
  canvas.style.width = width + 'px'
  canvas.style.height = height + 'px'
  canvas.getContext('2d').scale(ratio, ratio)

  return canvas
}

function setupCanvas() {
  const canvas = createHiPPICanvas(500, 300)

  const world = new World(canvas)

  world.loadWorld()
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  setupCanvas()
})
```

## Here is the rest of the code:

**World.js**

```
export default class World {
  constructor(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
  }

  loadWorld() {
    const border = new Border(this.canvas, this.ctx)
    border.draw()

    const ball = new Ball({
      canvas: this.canvas,
      innerColor: '#44CCFF',
      outerThickness: 1,
      pos: { x: 10, y: 10 },
      radius: 10,
      initVelocity: { xV: 10, yV: 15 },
    })

    const ball2 = new Ball({
      canvas: this.canvas,
      innerColor: '#E0FF4F',
      outerThickness: 1,
      pos: { x: 50, y: 100 },
      radius: 10,
      initVelocity: { xV: 20, yV: 19 },
    })

    ball.spawn()
    ball2.spawn()

    cost playWorld = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(playWorld, canvas)
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.canvas.clientWidth, this.ctx.canvas.clientHeight)
      ball.animate()
      ball2.animate()
    }

    playWorld()
  }
}
```

**Ball.js**

```
import getStopPos from './getStopPos.js'

export default class Ball {
  constructor({ canvas, outerThickness, innerColor, pos, radius, initVelocity }) {
    ;(this.canvas = canvas), (this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d'))
    this.pos = pos
    this.radius = radius
    this.velocity = initVelocity

    this.ctx.fillStyle = innerColor
    this.ctx.lineWidth = outerThickness
  }

  spawn() {
    this.ctx.beginPath()
    this.ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
    this.ctx.fill()
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.outerColor
    this.ctx.stroke()
    this.ctx.closePath()
  }

  move({ xV = 0, yV = 0 }) {
    ;(this.pos.x += xV), (this.pos.y += yV), this.spawn()
  }

  animate() {
    const { clientHeight, clientWidth } = this.ctx.canvas

    const heightStopBottom = getStopPos(clientHeight, this.radius)
    const heightStopTop = this.radius
    const widthStopRight = getStopPos(clientWidth, this.radius)
    const widthtStopLeft = this.radius

    const friction = 0.04
    const gravity = 0.2
    const bounce = Math.sqrt(2.3 * gravity)

    this.pos.y > heightStopBottom ? (this.velocity.yV *= -bounce) : (this.velocity.yV += gravity)

    if (this.velocity.xV < friction && this.velocity.xV > -friction) {
      this.velocity.xV = 0
    } else {
      this.pos.x < 0 ? (this.velocity.xV += friction) : (this.velocity.xV -= friction)
    }

    if (this.pos.y < heightStopTop) this.velocity.yV *= -bounce
    if (this.pos.x > widthStopRight) this.velocity.xV *= -bounce

    if (this.pos.x < widthtStopLeft) this.velocity.xV *= -bounce

    this.move(this.velocity)
  }
}
```

**getStopPos.js**

```
export default function getStopPos(canvasDimension, radius) {
  return canvasDimension - 1 - radius
}
```

I have tried passing in the context that we get from `World.js` on to `Ball.js` and it still was the same... It is as if the state of `this.ctx.fillStyle` is shared by both `ball` and `ball2`.

I may not have a good grasp of OOP but shouldn't `this.ctx` be of the scope of the object `this` and that it shouldn't affect another object's property with the same property name?

Comment: You never define `outerColor ` when creating the objects.

Comment: It's alright I don't want to put any color to `outerColor` yet :) But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That's odd, as you're using `outerColor` in the code: `this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.outerColor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas elements only have one `2d` drawing context.

```js
"use strict";
 let ctxBall1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
 let ctxBall2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
 console.log( "Multiple calls to getContext('2d') on the same convas return the same ctx object: ",
    ctxBall1 === ctxBall2);
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```

Hence copying the canvas context to ball objects in the Ball constructor with

```
(this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d'))
```

simply takes a copy of the canvas context without creating a new one - you can leave out "as if" in your description of the behaviour.

I should expect setting canvas `fillStyle` with the `innerColor` recorded in the `Ball` instance,  in the `spawn` method before filling the path, would fix the problem. Use of `outerColor` would require similar treatment when coded.

Note supporting different outer thicknesses would also require resetting ball's stroke width in `spawn` as well. That is to say any and all context properties that differ between balls must be set in `spawn` before redrawing them.

Comment: If I could vote this answer I would. Thank you for this insight @traktor!

It's as you expected, setting the canvas `fillStyle` in the `spawn` method has fixed the problem perfect :) .